# Remove theme generated custom css from category pages wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and trying to modify the exiting theme. Actually, theme has been generating custom css code and adding to wp_head.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_css_generator', 10);
```

Now I want to remove the existing code and add my own css on category pages as I want to clean up the code and remove unwanted or repeated css.

I followed this article http://surefirewebservices.com/wordpress/how-to-use-remove_action-with-conditional-tags and added the code something like this:

```
add_action('wp_head','remove_theme_custom_css');
function remove_theme_custom_css() {
    if (is_category() ) {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'custom_css_generator',10,0);
    }
}
```

But its not working. Please help me resolving this issue.

**I added this function to child-theme's functions.php**

Comment: it's working just is categories with this function : is_category,try deleting if statement.

Comment: could you please send the code how you are saying. I tried and it says syntax error, unexpected 'remove_action'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nearly there, it is just your priority and accepted arguments that is wrong

Your priority is `10`, which means that your `remove_action` is being executed the same time as the `add_action`. I suspect that you are doing your changes in a child theme, actually your remove function will run before the action is added, thus is won't work at all. You have to wait for an action to ececute first before you can remove it. You'll need to add your function at a lower priority, which translates to a higher number

[`remove_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) does not accept a forth parameter, so just delete that

So, to make your code work, do the following

```
add_action('wp_head','remove_theme_custom_css');
function remove_theme_custom_css() {
    if (is_category()) {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'custom_css_generator', 20);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This should also work

```
if (is_category()) {
   remove_action('wp_head', 'custom_css_generator', 20);
}
```

Comment: No success. I thought it was almost done. Even pasted the code in main theme functions.php but still not working. Pulling my hairs out.

Comment: Please see my update. Made a mistake, sorry about that

Comment: Don't know why **remove_action** is not working and rest other things working.

Comment: I tried in main theme functions.php and child-theme functions.php both

Comment: No working for me. I dont think its going to work. Must be some other code also need to be modified.

Comment: That is my thought as well. What theme are you using. This is why I hate adding css the way it is done in this theme. You have tons of trouble removing it later on

Comment: Its a Newspaper4 theme from themeforest. Anyway, thanks for your patience and support Pieter :)

Comment: No problem. If I'm correct, you have paid for that theme. You should demand support from them, also, demand a refund if they don't want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the header.php file or potentially another php file which has the PHP functions for your theme you are likely to find something similar to this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_stylesheet' );
```

Which loads the style.css file for your theme.

If you do not want that to be loaded on your category pages you should first figure out what type of page it is exactly and you could wrap the above statement in a wordpress conditional such as this:

```
if ( ! ( is_category() ) ) { // is_category defines any category archive page
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_stylesheet' );
}
```

This means, if the page is not a category archive page, load the theme stylesheet.  If it is a category archive page, do not load the theme stylesheet.

Wordpress references:

[is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

[get_stylesheet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet)

[wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: This will break your complete styling on that particular pages :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help but actually its a php file with a function named custom_css_generator as mentioned above having lots of css code and added it to wp_head using add_action('wp_head', 'td_css_generator', 10);

Comment: Use the conditional in this function: custom_css_generator  Whats the code in that function look like?

Comment: That's some horrible looking WP theme code if I ever did see any..  I'm sorry for you.  I guess you could wrap everything inside the function in the conditional function.  Or you'd be better off rewriting that whole function.. you can get more info on how to appropriately write this function here:  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/05/the-wordpress-theme-customizer-a-developers-guide/  (there's a good code example about half way down the page)

Comment: Or, you know what you could do, is just let the stylesheet stay as it is, and when you write your new style, just write it in such a way that it overwrites any existing style definitions.  There are various ways to do this using CSS specificity for example